# PyQGIS OpenLayers map is not seen correctly in PNG file saved through QgsComposition, Looks like partially loaded

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-openlayers-plugin

I have created a Python script to create a map which contains three layers. One is a polygon layer of administrative boundaries, one is point layer, one is an OpenLayers plugin map.

I want to export this as an image in PNG format. I do this using QgsComposition class as suggested in this link:
http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/composer.html

However in the resulting picture it seems like the picture was exported before the OpenLayers map was fully loaded. In the picture you can see few tiles from the map while other area is full white. Is it some kind of refresh problem or I am not doing it correctly?

Please help.

[image: Here is how looks]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found alternative to OpenLayers plugin. I used WMS format in GDAL Check below links

http://www.gdal.org/frmt_wms.html
http://www.gdal.org/frmt_wms_googlemaps_tms.xml

I loaded the WMS service as raster layer in QGIS and then used QgsMapRendererParallelJob class to render the map.

```
mapSettings = iface.mapCanvas().mapSettings()
mapSettings.setOutputSize(QSize(1600,1100))
mapSettings.setOutputDpi(200)

mapRenderJob = QgsMapRendererSequentialJob(mapSettings)
mapRenderJob.start()
mapRenderJob.waitForFinished()
image = mapRenderJob.renderedImage()
```

This gets me the map correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The OpenLayers plugin doesn't support being exported via the composer at this stage.

Comment: Is there any other way to accomplish this task?

Comment: Are there plans to do so?

Comment: No idea it's a 3rd party plugin